# Tensorflow | Feeding a Placeholder under tf.train.Supervisor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have used Supervisor sessions before to manage FIFOQueues with no problems. However, I am running into an issue with the simple code below, which gives me error message:

> ```
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'W' with dtype float
>    [[Node: W = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=<unknown>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
> ```

```
import tensorflow as tf
LOG_DIR = 'log/sv/'

def using_supervisor ():
    with tf.Graph ().as_default ():
        W = tf.placeholder (tf.float32, name = 'W')
        W = tf.multiply (W, 100)
        moving_mean = tf.random_normal (shape = [10], mean = W, stddev = 1)

        tf.summary.histogram ("moving_mean", moving_mean)
        summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all ()

        sv = tf.train.Supervisor (logdir = LOG_DIR)
        with sv.managed_session () as sess:
            K = 2
            for i in range (K):
                result = sess.run (summary_op, feed_dict = {W: float (i)})
        sess.close ()

#----------------------------------------        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    using_supervisor ()
```

Any thoughts?

Obviously, there's no valid reason to use Supervised session for this simple program since I am not making advantage of it but just confused why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tf.train.Supervisor is deprecated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6263)! Thanks tensorflow developers for the proper warning message! Switched to tf.train.MonitoredSession and it works!

```
import tensorflow as tf
LOG_DIR = 'log/'

def run ():
    with tf.Graph ().as_default ():
        W = tf.placeholder (tf.float32, name = 'W')
        W = tf.multiply (W, 100)
        moving_mean = tf.random_normal (shape = [10], mean = W, stddev = 1)

        tf.summary.histogram ("moving_mean", moving_mean)
        summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all ()

        with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession () as sess:
            K = 2
            for i in range (K):
                result = sess.run (summary_op, feed_dict = {W: float (i)})

#----------------------------------------        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run ()
```